# Relative path from a new html window not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, relative-path, absolute-path

The absolute path is working from a new window open from the main window using Jquery
 Supply.php opens a new HTML window. The script in it is given below

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  //alert('test');
$('.Supply').click(function(){
     //alert('test');
     var inputData='EntryID='+$(this).attr('id');
     //alert(inputData + 'test');
     //return false;
     var x = screen.width/2 - 700/2;
   var y = screen.height/2 - 450/2;
   var myWindow = window.open('MessForm/MessCheck.php?'+inputData, 'MsgWindow', 'height=485,width=900,left='+x+',top='+y);
     
   });
   });
 </script>
```

And inside the MessCheck.php page, I have the script as below

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Submitall').click(function(){
     var inputData=$('#ID_Entry-form').serialize();
    // alert(inputData);
     //return false; 
  $.ajax({
     method:'post',
     data:$('#ID_PFD-form').serialize(),
         url:'http://localhost:8090/TEST/Db_function/php_insert_TempTransac.php',
     //1-->url:'/Db_function/php_insert_TempTransac.php',
     //2-->url:'../Db_function/php_insert_TempTransac.php',
     //3-->url:'./Db_function/php_insert_TempTransac.php',
     
     
     
     success:function(data){
      
      console.log(data);
      //alert(data.trim());
     
     }
     });     
   });
   });
</script>
```

The absolute path is working find but the relative path(1or 2 or3 *Commented*) is not working

Comment: Might it have to do with the port number you specify in the absolute path, but not in the relative paths?

Comment: I'm also missing these: `url:'/TEST/Db_function/php_insert_TempTransac.php'` and `url:'Db_function/php_insert_TempTransac.php'`.

Comment: relative works in other php files I have which are open on the main browser but not working from new window opened.the port number have no issue with relative path

Comment: @KIKO I have tried that also.